# Saving jTextPane text not working properly

Tags: netbeans, save, jtextpane, filechooser

I'm trying to save a "history" I'm building after you sent a command from a line, so every time you press Enter the commands goes to the jTextPane with a line separator... However when I save the file it doesn't seem to get the line separator. Example, my jTextPane has something like:

```
Create database user
use database user
show tables from database
```

Instead of saving the workspace just like that, it gives me this:

Create database useruse database usershow tables from database

What should I do? Here's my code

```
String ar;
    String TEXTO = jTextPane1.getText() + System.lineSeparator();
    FileFilter ft = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", ".txt");
    FC.setFileFilter(ft);
    int returnVal = FC.showSaveDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        java.io.File saved_file = FC.getSelectedFile();
        String file_name = saved_file.toString();
        File archivo;
        ar = "" + file_name + ".txt";

        archivo = new File(ar);
        try {
            if (saved_file != null) {
                try (FileWriter GUARDADO = new FileWriter(ar)) {
                    GUARDADO.write(TEXTO);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            System.out.println(exp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way. The "System.lineSeparator()" is something I tried but it won't work since it puts the line after it reads everything from the TextPane

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
jTextPane1.getDocument().getText(0,jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength());
```

Comment: That could be a solution but yet... Is not writting everything the way I want to, because it is still creating only one line with every word it founds instead of giving the line separator

Comment: I tried using the sample input you gave and it seems to work fine. Please explain, if something else I'm not getting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to use /n instead of System.lineSeparator. The JTextPane behavior doesn't depends on the System.